# Convert postgresql join and group by query to JPA criteria API

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

I am having trouble to converting the following postgresql query (with a join and a group by) to JPA criteria API for a Spring Boot, JPA, Hibernate application:

```
select u.id, u.full_name, count(*) project_applications_count from users u
join project_applications pa on pa.created_by = u.id
group by u.id, u.full_name
having count(*) >= 1 and count(*) <= 5
```

The tables look like this:

```
create table project_applications (
    id serial primary key,
    ...
    city_id integer not null references cities (id),
    created_by integer not null references users (id)
);

create table users (
    id serial primary key,
    ...
    full_name varchar(100) not null
);
```

And the entities look like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "project_applications")
public class ProjectApplication {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "created_by")
    private User createdBy;

    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "full_name")
    private String fullName;

    ...
}
```

I tried searching online for a solution but every exemple I found was using either a join or group by, but not both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using @akortex's idea with projections, I think something like this should work:

```
public class UserSummary {
    private Long id;
    private String fullName;
    private Long count;

    public UserSummary() {
    }

    public UserSummary(Long id, String fullName, Long count) {
        this.id = id;
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.count = count;
    }

    ... (getters and setters)

}

public List<UserSummary> getSummaries(Integer minProjectAppsCount, Integer maxProjectAppsCount) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = _entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<UserSummary> query = cb.createQuery(UserSummary.class);  

    Root<ProjectApplication> projectApp = query.from(ProjectApplication.class);
    Join<ProjectApplication, User> userJoin = projectApp.join("createdBy", JoinType.INNER);
    query.multiselect(userJoin.get("id"), userJoin.get("fullName"), cb.count(projectApp))
        .groupBy(userJoin.get("id"), userJoin.get("fullName"));

    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
    if (minProjectAppsCount != null ) {
        Predicate p = cb.ge(cb.count(projectApp), minProjectAppsCount);
        predicates.add(p);
    }

    if (maxProjectAppsCount != null ) {
        Predicate p = cb.le(cb.count(projectApp), maxProjectAppsCount);
        predicates.add(p);
    }

    
    query.having(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));

    return _entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially look into [projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections.dtos) in order to achieve what you want.

For example consider the following projection and repository:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ProjectApplicationSummary {

    private Long id;
    private String fullName;
    private Long count;

}
```

And:

```
@Repository
public interface ProjectApplicationRepository extends JpaRepository<ProjectApplication, Long> {

    @Query(
        """
        SELECT new com.example.springdemo.entities.ProjectApplicationSummary(u.id, u.fullName, count(pa))
        FROM User u, ProjectApplication pa
        GROUP BY u.id, u.fullName
        """
    )
    List<ProjectApplicationSummary> getSummaries();

}
```

You will most likely need to tweak the query a bit (which revolves experimenting with `JPQL`) but other than that, the basic idea is there.

Comment: The min and max count parameters are optional and that is why I was thinking of the criteria API (predicates list) instead of JPQL.
The projection idea is nice but do you have an example using the criteria API instead of JPQL? Thank you, @akortex!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure in my solution, but it should be similar. I took an idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63471849/how-to-write-query-with-additional-count-column-using-jpa-criteria-builder). Maybe it helps you to resolve your problem.

```
    public static Specification<User> getUsers() {
            return Specification.where((root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
                CriteriaQuery<User> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(User.class);

                Subquery<Long> subQuery = criteriaQuery.subquery(Long.class);
                Root<ProjectApplication> subRoot = subQuery.from(ProjectApplication.class);

                subQuery
                    .select(criteriaBuilder.count(subRoot))
                    .where(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("id"), subRoot.get("createdBy").get("id")));

                query
                    .multiselect(criteriaBuilder.construct(root.get("id"), root.get("fullName")))
                    .groupBy(root.get("id"), root.get("fullName"))
                    .having(criteriaBuilder.and(
                            criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(subQuery.getSelection(), 1L),
                            criteriaBuilder.lessThanOrEqualTo(subQuery.getSelection(), 5L)));

                return query.getRestriction();
        });
    }
```